# bjam scripts output a define

Tags: boost, bjam

Is it possible to write to console a define from a bjam script? I have something like $(PROJECT_ROOT) and I want to echo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
echo $(PROJECT_ROOT) ;
```